# Index broken or missing of AVI encoded with Media Foundation

Tags: ms-media-foundation, avi

So I am generating an uncompressed avi using Media Foundation. The frames of the avi originate from in RAM images which are processed.
I manage to generate an avi file which can be played in our own application and in windows media player without a problem. However, when the avi file is played using VLC we get the message: "Index of the file is missing or broken". We can play as is but we want to get rid of the error message. (We also do the same for the h264 format using Media Foundation and this does not include the problem).

I have researched the problem quite extensive and found a possible explanation of the problem here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/114418/mftranscodecontainertype-avi-not-creating-index.html

Another remarks I saw somewhere is that Media Foundation does have a bug in writing the index but I am not sure about this.

I have not figured out a workaround or solution yet. So hopefully someone over here can help.

To give an idea of how the avi is generated (pseudo code):

1. MFStartUp()
2. MFCreateFile(MF_ACCESSMODE_READWRITE, MF_OPENMODE_DELETE_IF_EXIST, MF_FILEFLAGS_NONE, pinnedFilename, &pByteStream);
3. MFCreateAVIMediaSink(pByteStream, pMediaType, NULL, &pMediaSink);
4. MFCreateSinkWriterFromMediaSink(pMediaSink, pAttr, pSinkWriter);
5. pSinkWriter->SetInputMediaType(_videoStreamIndex, spTypeIn, NULL)
6. pSinkWriter->BeginWriting()
7. Add Frames
8. SinkWriter->Finalize()
9. MFShutdown();

Comment: I tried it by putting 1920x1080 uncompressed RGB24 into there in 7. of yours. That seemed to work, just that 30 sec  30 fps video was about 6 GB.

Comment: File size is huge yes but that is not very important for my use case. So were you able to play it with VLC without getting the ""Index of the file is missing or broken" pop-up? If so, it would be interesting to know which version of MF you used.